# How to intersect more than 2 polygons using Turf.js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

We use Mapbox GL JS 1.12.0 in our Vue.js project. I need to create intersection objects if I have 2 or more polygons. But, I'm able to do it with 2 polygons only. The code looks as following:

```
import * as turf from '@turf/turf';

export function createIntersection(features) {
  // features = 3 polygons on the screen bellow
  const intersection = turf.intersect(...features);

  return intersection;
}
```

The screenshots:

1. Unselected polygons:

[image]

2. Selected polygons

[image]

3. After code execution

[image]

As you can see there is only 1 intersection object created.

How to do it with more than 2 polygons?

Comment: You need to iterate over all the pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[turf.intersect()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) can only intersect 2 polygons.

If you want to intersect multiple polygons you can intersect each polygon with each other polygon with [turf.intersect()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect) and then combine the results using [turf.combine()](https://turfjs.org/docs/#combine).

Here is some example code:

```
const polygonA = ...;
const polygonB = ...;
const polygonC = ...;

const allIntersections = {
  type: 'FeatureCollection',
  features: [
    turf.intersect(polygonA, polygonB),
    turf.intersect(polygonA, polygonC),
    turf.intersect(polygonB, polygonC),
  ],
};

const combinedIntersection = turf.combine(allIntersections);
```

Comment: Small correction that it should be `FeatureCollection`. Nice workaround though! A shame Turf JS doesn't simply allow to intersect multipolygons as claimed, however...